# Cannot create maintenance plan, I get the message "The task with the name '' and the creation name is not registered for use on this computer"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, maintenance, maintenance-plans

I just installed SQL server 2016 (Standard edition) on a new server,
I'm trying to add a Maintenance plan (I've tried back up plan, rebuild indexes and many more)
I'm getting a weird message when I'm trying to open the task:

> The task with the name "back up plan database task" and the creation name is not registered for use on this computer.

[image]

At first, I thought it was a permission issue so I went to services.msc and change the login as to a user with administrator permissions - still not working.
Restarting the server - still not working.

Comment: Are you using SSMS 18 preview? I have been getting similar errors with that build, but 17.9 works fine.

Comment: check this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b62a4183-d04a-4cd7-91dc-8836c3a292ec/the-task-with-the-name-and-the-creation-name-is-not-registered-for-use-on-this-computer?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been having the same issue with SSMS 18 (preview 4) when trying to access any maintenance plan tasks.

I [opened this item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35698531-cannot-open-maintenance-plan-steps-in-ssms-18-prev) on the feedback site to capture the bug. Feel free to upvote if this describes the issue you're experiencing.

For now I am just using 17.x versions of SSMS to do any maintenance plan related tasks, since you can have both installed side-by-side.

---

The bug was acknowledged on 10/15 and it looks like MS is working on a fix, so hopefully the next release resolves the issue.

Comment: Yea that was the problem, I accidentally install the SSMS18. Thanks.